# DB2 before trigger syntax

Tags: sql, database, plsql, db2, db2-express-c

I've defined this trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER actualizarSaldoIngreso
BEFORE INSERT ON Ingreso
FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
BEGIN ATOMIC
    UPDATE Cliente SET Nombre = 'Juan' WHERE DNI = '87366034M';
END;
```

But DB2 returns this error:

```
An unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following "RE DNI = '87366034M'". Expected tokens may include: "<delim_semicolon>"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change terminator like this :

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
CREATE TRIGGER actualizarSaldoIngreso
BEFORE INSERT ON Ingreso
FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
BEGIN ATOMIC
    UPDATE Cliente SET Nombre = 'Juan' WHERE DNI = '87366034M';
END@
--#SET TERMINATOR ;
```

With a different terminator, the batch doesn't execute prematurely.